# Android's StrictMode - How do I use it properly, and why is my app not working without it?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've started playing around with simple concepts like binding ListViews and fetching JSON data to an adapter which fills a ListView. The example shipped with the following code:

```
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll()
            .penaltyLog()
            .build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

At first I wasn't too concerned about the

```
// Testing only. Do NOT USE IN PRODUCTION!
```

comment, until I removed the policy code, which caused my app to start throwing ANRs every time it returned the HttpResponse.

Looks like I'm getting a 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException' exception. Now, I can understand why you wouldn't want any networking code running on your UI thread, but why would StrictMode even allow you to do this in the first place if it's guaranteed to throw runtime exceptions?

On the same note, could someone please explain the StrictMode snippet above? I've read the Android dev docs about it but I'm still a little confused as to how it allows the code to run.

My only theory is a pseudo-explanation below:

For the current thread, detect all illegal operations. Log the problem, but ignore it. Set the current thread's policy to use this rule.

Am I close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from api 9 you can not directly call network operation on main thread instead you can do so using AsyncTask. have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) for more information.

Comment: +1, although this would be a much better answer if you provided some example code.

Comment: +1 Tutorial looks really decent, will give it a read tonight, thanks.

Comment: @Rudi there are many examples available on internet and also one example is available on the tutorial link

Comment: @drminnaar yeah it is please go through it will give you many details about network operations asynchronously

Comment: That's not really the point, this is very close to a link only answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145901/246959